# How can I run gsettings from a GNOME Shell Extension?

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, sh

How can I trigger a `.sh` script for the extension?
Or even how can I access gsettings?
I'm trying to create an extension that does this function:

```
if $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons); then
  new="false"
else
  new="true"
fi gsettings set
org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons $new
```

Comment: To access gsettings from a script -in whatever language- is not an issue, but what has that got to do with a shell extension? Not sure on the title.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank your for your reply. i'm creating a gnome shell extension , a noobish in that, and i was wondering how can i access gsettings in extension.js or if not possible , how can i run this .sh script or convert it to js format ~

Answer (score 0):

You likely will be helped by the Gnome Shell extension [argos](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos). It allows you to easily add a button with a dropdown menu to the panel to expose functionality, based on either a simple bash script, or any executable that writes to standard output.

Following simple script already will do the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Desktop Icons $current"
echo "---"
echo "Turn desktop icons ON | bash='gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true' terminal=false"
echo "Turn desktop icons OFF | bash='gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false' terminal=false"
```

Install the extension and make sure it is turned on. Make the script executable, and drop it into the folder .config/argos in your Home folder. An item "Desktop Icons" will appear in your top bar. Clicking the button will gives you the options to turn the desktop icons on or off.

Comment: that's cool! but i was hoping to create my own extension for that purpose and publish it.